# powershell function parameter types

Tags: powershell

have the following function:

```
function appendToSB([System.Text.StringBuilder]$sb,
                    [string]$value){
    [void]$sb.append($value)
    $sb
}

$sb = new-object -typename system.text.stringbuilder
$sb = appendToSb($sb, "1,")

$sb.tostring() | out-host
```

i want to build string using StringBuilder using my function for that, but i receive the following error:

> appendToSB : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'sb'.
>   Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of ty pe "System.Object[]"
>   to type "System.Text.StringBuilder". At E:\powershell\test.ps1:8
>   char:11
>   + appendToSb([system.text.stringbuilder]$sb, "1,")
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [appendToSB], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,appendToSB

does anybody can explain how function/function parameter/return values works in powershell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Classic PowerShell issue.  You don't use parens or comma separated args when calling commands or functions e.g.:

```
appendToSb $sb "1,"
```

You only use that syntax when calling .NET methods.  If you use `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` it will catch this sort of issue.  What you passed ($sb, "1,") is how you would pass an array to a single parameter.  Technically the parens aren't needed but don't change the value i.e. you could pass an array like this as well `$sb, ","`.